# How deserialize xml to object Net 6?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, .net-6.0

I have xml string in input:

```
<ActivationRequest xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataLayer.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Key>key</Key>
    <Edition i:nil="true"/>
    <HardwareId>542D</HardwareId>
    <IntelliLockFlags>BIOS CPU</IntelliLockFlags>
    <MachineName>nikolas</MachineName>
    <Product>studio</Product>
    <UseMacHID>false</UseMacHID>
    <Version xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
        <a:_Build>88</a:_Build>
        <a:_Major>6</a:_Major>
        <a:_Minor>4</a:_Minor>
        <a:_Revision>0</a:_Revision>
    </Version>
</ActivationRequest>
```

And my deserializer:

```
public static Parameters DeserializeFromXml<T>(this string xml)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;

        var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Parameters));
        return deserializer.ReadObject(stream) as Parameters; // error
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
public class Parameters
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string HardwareId { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public Version Version { get; set; }
    public bool UseMacHID { get; set; }
    public LockFlags IntelliLockFlags { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
}

[Flags]
public enum LockFlags
{
    Empty = 0,
    BIOS = 1,
    CPU = 2
}
```

And this worked on .Net Core 2.2. But after I changed version on .Net 6 I begin get error:

> Error in line 1 position 144. Expecting element 'ActivationParameters' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataLayer.NetStandard.BusinessLayer.Activation'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ActivationRequest', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataLayer.Models'.'

Any ideas

Comment: isn't that obvious? YOu de-serialize an `ActivationRequest` (whatever that is) into a `Paramaters`-class. We have no clue how those two things are related, though. I doubt that code above worked in any version of .Net, unless that's not your *real* code.

Comment: Please [edit] question to show the [mre] of the code that "worked on .Net Core 2.2". Make sure to inline **minimal** XML as a string constant in the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ActivationRequest));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        ActivationRequest result = (ActivationRequest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

classes

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataLayer.Models")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataLayer.Models", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ActivationRequest
{
    public string KeyField { get; set; }
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this.KeyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.KeyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable = true)]
    public object Edition { get; set; }

    public string HardwareId { get; set; }

    public string IntelliLockFlags { get; set; }

    public string MachineName { get; set; }

    public string Product { get; set; }

    public bool UseMacHID { get; set; }

    public ActivationRequestVersion Version { get; set; }

}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataLayer.Models")]
public partial class ActivationRequestVersion
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System")]
    public byte _Build { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System")]
    public byte _Major { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System")]
    public byte _Minor { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System")]
    public byte _Revision { get; set; }
}
```